# jwplayer embedded with recent flash with html5 back end cant hide controls or add autoplay and loop

Tags: html, loops, controls, jwplayer, autoplay

Hey all,
After the unfortunate realization that Firefox is just not going to play nice with an embedded HTML5 video with my server set up, I've decided to go the JW Player route, since it's compatible with iPads and iPhones.

I can get the file to show up on my page, but it's big and heavy. I would like for it to be just the video, no controls. Autoplay and on loop.

Can you help me out? Here's the code...

```
        <div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>
```

jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
    file: "Video/fernando.m4v",
    height: 520,
    width: 780,
   });

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
jwplayer("container").setup({ 
  flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
  file: "Video/fernando.m4v", 
  height: 520, 
  width: 780,
  autostart: true,
  repeat: "always",
  controlbar: "none"
});
```